# Python: synatx error: string format not correct

Tags: python

I wrote this sensical line of code but Python says there's a syntax error:

```
plt.savefig(f"./emvdata/{file_path.replace('G:\\emvdata\\MeasurementData\\Clinical-Data-20200220-Stage-1\\output\\', '_').replace('\\', '_')}.png")
```

I'm aware of " and ' usage, but still it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backslashes are forbidden within the braces of an f-string. The behavior was deemed too confusing, no matter what behavior was chosen. It's far more readable to move such expressions out of the f-string, so they decided to go with that.

This is made fairly explicit in the exception message:

```
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
```

Take the giant expression you had in the braces, and compute it outside the f-string.

Comment: It worked! 
I still don't see any confusion with the backslashes and how f string work.

Comment: @AlexDeft: You don't, because you see one possible behavior, and it doesn't even occur to you that it could work differently. Other people only see a different possible behavior, and it doesn't even occur to them that it could work differently. People disagreed about things like what phase or phases of f-string processing should interpret backslashes, and I believe the behavior worked differently from what you want back in the pre-release builds where backslashes were allowed.